# How to get url of file uploaded on AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am uploading image file on **Amazon AWS S3 bucket** using **Java**.

I am using following maven dependency -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.28.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am able to upload the file, also able to download the contents. But I want to return the image url to the user.

How can I get the image url immediately after uploading on s3 bucket?

Here is my java code -

```
public void uploadProfile(InputStream fileInputStream, String fileName)  {      

        AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials("MY-ACCESS-KEY", "MY-SECRET-KEY"));
        String bucketName = "MyBucket";
        String key = "MyKey";

        try {

            System.out.println("Listing buckets");
            for (Bucket bucket : s3client.listBuckets()) {
                System.out.println(" - " + bucket.getName());
            }
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file\n");

            s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, fileInputStream, new ObjectMetadata()).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));

            System.out.println("Downloading an object");
            S3Object object = s3client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
            System.out.println("Content-Type: "  + object.getObjectMetadata().getContentType());
            displayTextInputStream(object.getObjectContent());

            System.out.println("Listing objects");
            ObjectListing objectListing = s3client.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
                    .withBucketName(bucketName)
                    .withPrefix("My"));
            for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
                System.out.println(" - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " +
                                   "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() + ")");
            }
            System.out.println();

         } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
            System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
            ase.printStackTrace();            
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
            ace.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void displayTextInputStream(InputStream input) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        while (true) {
            String line = reader.readLine();
            if (line == null) break;

            System.out.println("    " + line);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

I have tried to hit the url : `https://MyBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfilename`

But its showing message in xml as -

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>64358C14C976A2CB</RequestId>
   <HostId>
      ZQ+DAaocOLxR/TmfEMGLcYm4Zk4Kl1vCKjciYiXKF1gYH5Lhj6oM4rd/o/4+SLVb
   </HostId>
</Error>
```

So how can I get the image url immediately after uploading on s3 bucket?

Answer (score 1):

This is a security error. There is a good chance that you are using the good URL, but you don't have the right to access the file. You need to change the permissions to download: Everyone. Then the file will be accessible via the internet for anyone.
If you don't want to do this, then you can set up different permissions like: Authenticated users, then you are able to access the file from an EC2 instance with the right IAM User attached.

Comment: Ok so its permission issue, I will look into, but I thought through coding I will get the url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to click the particular file in S3 bucket and choose the option as **make public** for time being. It will be accessed from anywhere.